# call ng-change when model has changed in angular component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

i have update to angular 1.5 and now want to use components instead of directives. My problem is that my ngModel will not run ng-change after i have changed my value. all solutions i found didn't match my problem.

i have following component

```
<date-picker ng-model="$ctrl.fromDate" ng-change="$ctrl.updateData()">
</date-picker>
```

my date-picker directive looks like (i reduced the code because there is a lot of non relevant stuff)
i use babelify for my code

```
import template from './datePicker.jade';
import moment from 'moment';

class datePicker {

  constructor(
    $scope,
    $element,
    $attrs
  ) {
    console.log(this);
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$element = $element;
    this.$attrs = $attrs
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    this.updateView();
  }

  changeDate(day) {
    this.ngModel = day;
    this.updateView();
  }

datePicker.$inject = [
  '$scope',
  '$element',
  '$attrs'
];

export default {
  controller: datePicker,
  bindings: {
    ngModel: '=',
  },
  template: template(),
};
```

My solution with the directive way was defining in the link function a scope.updateModel function which sets the view value of my model. That works, but its ugly, i dont want to use link functions anymore